# SP Online - SharePoint Hosted Add'in - type(extension) of pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, file, aspx

I'm beginner developer for SharePoint-Online. I want to know what is the best practice of extension of my pages in sharePoint hosted addin.

a) .aspx extension b) .html extension c) .htm extension

[image]

Thank you previously, this is really helpful for me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.html` and `.htm` are absolutely identical.

In terms of apps there is no difference if you are creating `.aspx` or `.html`.
But you need to consider your requirements carefully. For example, if you need to host on your page some OOB web parts, for example XSLTListViewWebPart:

```html
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="full" Title="loc:full">
            <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/Faq" IsIncluded="True"
                NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="XsltListView web part" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW"
                Default="False" ViewContentTypeId="0x">
            </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

this is possible only in `aspx` page. If you need to put into your page any other SharePoint controls - you need `aspx`.

From the other side, `aspx` adds some html and js overhead in markup. If all above is not your requirement, and you are building modern angular (react) SPA application, for simplicity you can go ahead with `.html`.

From my perspective, it's safer and better to always use `.aspx`, because in future you may have a requirement to include some OOB controls into your existing page. In that case with '.html' you will be stucked. If you are building react\angular, just put markup inside `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">`.